# ClickHouse SQL driven access control replication

Tags: access-control, clickhouse

I'd like to enable SQL-driven Access Control and Account Management as mentioned in ClickHouse docs https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/access-rights/

However, it does not state whether sql-managed users are then replicated across cluster or have to be set per replica.

*I would move to sql-driven access control only if it was true. Now I have to manage xml files per replica. I see no big advantage in moving to SQL if it's either not replicated.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL-managed users are NOT replicated.

> I see no big advantage in moving to SQL if it's either not replicated.

SQL managed users allows you to GRANT SELECT by table.

---

Upd. Now users/grants/roles... can be synced (replicated) using zookeeper/keeper

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<clickhouse>
  <user_directories replace="replace">
    <users_xml>
      <path>/etc/clickhouse-server/users.xml</path>
    </users_xml>
    <replicated>
      <zookeeper_path>/clickhouse/mycluster/access/</zookeeper_path>
    </replicated>
  </user_directories>
</clickhouse>
```

(needs to re-run all RBAC SQLs)

Comment: So apart from the more granular permissions management there's no advantage over xml, right? If I consider xml easier to manage it makes sense to go with.